# Java - Regex, replace respectively

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have short pieces of text that can contain from 0 to N parameters, similarly to template libraries for web applications. Each parameter can have an optional default value :

```
bla bla bla {{paramA=defaultValA}} bla bla {{paramB}} bla bla bla
```

The name of the parameter is used to retrieve its string value from a string to string map.
What I need to do is replace these parameters (including `{{`, `}}`, and default value, if any) by the value of that parameter.

My problem is that, even if i manage to isolate all the parameters into separate strings :

```
{{paramA=defaultValA}}
{{paramB}}
```

And replace them by their value inside of these separate strings, I don't know how to place them back into the original input string above.

Assuming that I place my parameter values inside an array, is there a way to do some kind of "replace respectively" so that the Nth group (i.e Nth param) gets replaced by the Nth value in the parameter values array ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Ho maybe i found a way using .start(int) and .end(int) from the Matcher object. I'll see what i can do with that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple & dirty solution using `Pattern` and `Matcher`:

```
// the map of values
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
// adding paramB only
map.put("paramB", "Foo!");
String text = "bla bla bla {{paramA=defaultValA}} bla bla {{paramB}} bla bla bla";
//                           | escaped curly brackets
//                           |     | group 1: key
//                           |     |     | group 2: optional =defaultValue
//                           |     |     | | group3: default value if any
//                           |     |     | |       | escaped closing curly brackets
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{(\\w+)(=(\\w+))?\\}\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
// StringBuilder to build populated output
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
// keeping track of index for matching, starting at 0
int start = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    // adding to output so far
    output.append(text.substring(start, m.start()));
    // index is now end of match
    start = m.end();
    // paramX
    String key = m.group(1);
    // default value
    String defaultValue = m.group(3);
    // is in map?
    String value = map.get(key);
    // yes
    if (value != null) {
        output.append(value);
    }
    // not in map, checking for default value
    else if (defaultValue != null) {
        output.append(defaultValue);
    }
    // adding placeholder for no value found
    else {
        output.append("[value not found]");
    }
}
// adding text after last match
output.append(text.substring(start));

System.out.println(output);
```

**Output**

```
bla bla bla defaultValA bla bla Foo! bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `appendReplacement` to do that.

E.g:

```
String str = "bla bla bla {{paramA=defaultValA}} bla bla {{paramB}} bla bla bla";

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("paramA", null);
params.put("paramB", "toto");

String param;
String defaultValue;
int index;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{(.*?)\\}\\}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
StringBuffer strb = new StringBuffer();

while (matcher.find()) {
  defaultValue = "";
  param = matcher.group(1);

  if (param.contains("=")) {
    index = param.indexOf("=");
    defaultValue = param.substring(index + 1, param.length());
    param = param.substring(0, index);
  }

  Object ob = params.get(param);
  String value = ob != null ? ob.toString() : defaultValue;

  matcher.appendReplacement(strb, value);
}

matcher.appendTail(strb);

System.out.println(strb);
```

Output :

```
bla bla bla defaultValA bla bla toto bla bla bla
```